# Javascript/Jquery how to detect click in another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I got a parent window which have to open another one using open() method. Child-window contains just simple html document with a form stored in the same domain space. Now here's the question, how to detect from the parent window that submit button was clicked? I want to solve it the simplest and the most elegant way.

Thank You.

Comment: The child window should have an `opener` property referencing the parent window. From the child window, you can just do `window.opener.whatever()`. The parent window can also access the child window, just assign the result of calling `open` to a variable to get a handle to that window. All assuming they're on the same domain, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Most elegantly would be to take advantage of `window.parent.postMessage` function.

In child window

```
document.onclick = function() { window.parent.postMessage({message: 'clicked'}) }
```

In parent window

```
function messageReceived(e) {

    var data = e.data;

    // do something here

}

if(window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener('message', messageReceived);
else
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', messageReceived);
```

Comment: `parent` should probably be `opener`... but why use `postMessage`? Each window already has a handle to the other, you can just set some property or call a function directly